# Getting negative y-intercept of a line

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, slope

I am quite weak in mathematics and stuck in a problem. I am fitting the data points to a line and then computing the `y-intercept`. **Problem here is that sometimes the y-intercept becomes negative** which makes no sense to me. I have implemented an [algorithm](http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/line-of-best-fit.html) in `C#` and also used the following `MATLAB` code:

```
plot(time, f1, 'b*-', 'LineWidth', 2, 'MarkerSize', 15);
coeffs = polyfit(time, f1, 1);
% Get fitted values
fittedX = linspace(min(time), max(time), 200);
fittedY = polyval(coeffs, fittedX);
% Plot the fitted line
hold on;
plot(fittedX, fittedY, 'r-', 'LineWidth', 3);
```

Output figure is inserted below:

[image]

**`coeff(2)` should be the y-intercept which is negative in the my case.** Someone please explain this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your $x$-axis and your $y$-axis. $x = 0$ cannot be seen in the plot because it is far left. If you continue your line to the left (just straight continuation) it is for sure possible, that in $x = 0$ the corresponding $y$ value is negative.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) my data set doesn't contain any `0` value for `x` neither it contains any `-ve` value for `y`. This is a complete figure in which `x` starts from `0.79`

Comment: @ItbanSaeed  The intercept is where the red line extended a long way to the left crosses the $y$-axis (i.e where $x=0$).  Unlike the slope, it has no particular meaning here, and it is just a point. You could instead describe the red line by the slope and some other point it passes through, such as the mean of your data

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, now I understood your point :)